# auto click with if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var account = <?php @$_GET['account'];?>
if(account){
  jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('#btnModal').click();
  });
}
</script>
```

If without if statement, auto click is work correctly, but if i want to add if statement, auto click doesn't work correctly..

**what's wrong with the script..?**

Comment: try `var account = '<?php @$_GET['account'];?>';`

Comment: also do not use error suppressors when in dev mode.

Comment: *"auto click doesn't work correctly"* - Have you checked the browser's dev console for error messages?

Comment: Try to console.log `<?php @$_GET['account'];?>` and check what it has.

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes `"` to treat php `GET` value as string instead javascript variable and use `.trigger()` method to make auto click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var account = "<?php $_GET['account'] ?? '' ;?>";
  if(account){
  jQuery(function(){
      jQuery('#btnModal').trigger ("click");
  });
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `trigger();` - A call to `.trigger()` executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user.

Ref: - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var account = "<?php @$_GET['account'];?>"
if(account){
  jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('#btnModal').trigger( "click" );
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: `jQuery('#btnModal').click()` is supposed to work the same. So that's not an issue.

Comment: `jQuery('#btnModal').click()` actually fires the already attached `click` event. Please read the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: yeah, you are right. thanks for correcting me. in OP also, auto click is working without `if`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var account = <?php @$_GET['account'];?>
if(account){
  jQuery(function(e){
     jQuery('#btnModal').click();
  });
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var account = <?php @$_GET['account'];?>
    if(!account){
      });
    } else{
 jQuery(function(e){
         jQuery('#btnModal').click();
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

And finally this is work correct:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['account'])){?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
      jQuery('#btnModal').click();
    });
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks All..